# Confused about where I should start with pagination {$.getJSON, php image array}

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pagination

Here's how my code is setup now:

- user visits a certain link on the page
- `$.getJSON` sends a request to a php script
- php calls `scandir()` to create an array for the names of images (100s-1000s eventually but only a few now for testing, hence the need to add pagination)
- echos a json_encoded array
- `$.each` item is used to create a string variable that is a new  tag
- prepend string variable to a div container that is a inline display of images

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- have 50 items loaded with ajax at a time
- figure out how use `$.each` so that it works with the 50 item requirement
- figure out a different way to use `$.getJSON` so that not all xxxx number of images are requested at once

My questions:

- how can I make a request that's made only one time at the top of a javascript event stay active throughout the duration of a user clicking through these pages?

Php creating the array from scandir doesn't seem like it's a problem...maybe returning the whole array at once is a problem, but I can't figure how to create a loop that waits for user requests (clicking 'next' or 'prev') to iterate to the next 50 images in the array.

I imagine the best place to work on would be before or inside of `$.each`, somehow using a loop to wait for a following ajax request to create the next 50  tags and prepend them to the .

Here's the code:

```
     requestServer('ajax.php', flag);
            $('#Container').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.close_button').click(function() {
                $('#Container').fadeOut('slow');
                $('#welcome').fadeTo('slow',1);
                $('#i1,#i3,#i5').click(clickFade).mouseover(mouseOverFunc);
                $('#welcome').css({'position':'absolute','z-index':'10'});
            });
            flag = false;
            break;

    function requestServer(file, run_flag) {
        if (run_flag === true) {
            $.getJSON(file, function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    var html = "<img src='../images/"+val+"' style='display:inline' alt=null />";
                    $('#Container').prepend(html);
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

---

```
<?php
    $images = scandir('../includes/scrapedImages/');
    foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
        if ($image == '.' || $image == '..') {
            unset($images[$key]);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($images);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems wasteful to scan your image directory on each request.

Personally, I would write a PHP script that scans the directory once every X minutes (or is called on image upload).  Have it encode that into JSON, and save the output as a `.json` file somewhere on the server.

On the client side, `$.get` that JSON file.  Create 50 image elements, and set their `.src` to the URLs you retrieved from the `JSON` file.  Have a forward / back button at the bottom of the page that just re-sets those 50 image element `.src` to the next / previous set.

Optionally, you could also create an `img` element outside of the `DOM`, and then set an `interval` to change that element's `.src` every Z milliseconds.  Browsers will download the images even if they aren't attached in the `DOM`, and those loaded images will be cached.

Good luck :)